# Setting DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE under virtualenv?

Tags: django, virtualenvwrapper

I want the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE to change depending on what I say for workon.  It seemed to me that I want to set it in `.virtualenvs/postmkvirtualenv` but my trial had no effect.

```
ftpmaint@millstone:~$ cat ~/.virtualenvs/postmkvirtualenv
#!/bin/bash
# This hook is run after a new virtualenv is activated.
export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=newproject.settings
ftpmaint@millstone:~$ echo $DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE
az.settings
ftpmaint@millstone:~$ workon newproject
(newproject)ftpmaint@millstone:~$ echo $DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE
az.settings
```

Could someone set me straight; where should I put that export?

In addition, will it restore when I deactivate?  And if not, is there some natural way to restore it?

Comment: You can do this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8826534/how-can-i-correctly-set-django-settings-module-for-my-django-project-i-am-using/22452281#22452281

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You were on the right track, but you want to use the [`postactivate`](http://www.doughellmann.com/docs/virtualenvwrapper/scripts.html#postactivate) hook instead of `postmkvirtualenv`.

It won't restore automatically on deactivate. Thankfully there is [`postdeactivate`](http://www.doughellmann.com/docs/virtualenvwrapper/scripts.html#postdeactivate) hook that you can use to manually restore any environmental variables that you changed on activate.

Comment: Thank you (to both answerers).  The key was "activate", and I didn't understand that before.

Comment: Isn't the postactivate hook common for all environments? I think there is not much point of setting `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` there.

Comment: There's both a global and local version of the postactivate hook. For a local-only setting like this, you'd want to add the `export` to `$VIRTUAL_ENV/bin/postactivate` rather than the global `$VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_HOOK_DIR/postactivate`.

Answer (score 22):

One way I've done that before is by appending an export statement to the end of ./bin/activate

```
export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE="myproject.settings"
```