# How can I correctly set DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE for my Django project (I am using virtualenv)?

Tags: django, django-settings

I am having some trouble setting the DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE for my Django project.

I have a directory at `~/dev/django-project`.  In this directory I have a virtual environment which I have set up with virtualenv, and also a django project called "blossom" with an app within it called "onora".  Running `tree -L 3` from `~/dev/django-project/`  shows me the following:

```
.
├── Procfile
├── blossom
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __init__.pyc
│   ├── fixtures
│   │   └── initial_data_test.yaml
│   ├── manage.py
│   ├── onora
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── __init__.pyc
│   │   ├── admin.py
│   │   ├── admin.pyc
│   │   ├── models.py
│   │   ├── models.pyc
│   │   ├── tests.py
│   │   └── views.py
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── settings.pyc
│   ├── sqlite3-database
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── urls.pyc
├── blossom-sqlite3-db2
├── requirements.txt
└── virtual_environment
    ├── bin
    │   ├── activate
    │   ├── activate.csh
    │   ├── activate.fish
    │   ├── activate_this.py
    │   ├── django-admin.py
    │   ├── easy_install
    │   ├── easy_install-2.7
    │   ├── gunicorn
    │   ├── gunicorn_django
    │   ├── gunicorn_paster
    │   ├── pip
    │   ├── pip-2.7
    │   ├── python
    │   └── python2.7 -> python
    ├── include
    │   └── python2.7 -> /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7
    └── lib
        └── python2.7
```

I am trying to dump my data from the database with the command

```
django-admin.py dumpdata
```

My approach is to run `cd ~/dev/django-project` and then run `source virtual_environment/bin/activate` and then run `django-admin.py dumpdata`

However, I am getting the following error:

```
ImportError: Settings cannot be imported, because environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE is undefined.
```

I did some googling and found this page: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/settings/#designating-the-settings

which tell me that

> When you use Django, you have to tell it which settings you're using.
>   Do this by using an environment variable, DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE.  The
>   value of DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE should be in Python path syntax, e.g.
>   mysite.settings. Note that the settings module should be on the Python
>   import search path.

Following a suggestion at [Setting DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE under virtualenv?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7598793/setting-django-settings-module-under-virtualenv) I appended the lines

```
export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE="blossom.settings"
echo $DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE
```

to virtual_environment/bin/activate.  Now, when I run the activate command in order to activate the virtual environment, I get output reading:

```
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE set to blossom.settings
```

This looks good to me, but now the problem I have is that running

```
django-admin.py dumpdata
```

returns the following error:

```
ImportError: Could not import settings 'blossom.settings' (Is it on sys.path?): No module named blossom.settings
```

What am I doing wrong?  How can I check the`sys.path`?  How is this supposed to work?

Thanks.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Don't run `django-admin.py` for anything other than the initial project creation. For everything after that, use `manage.py`, which takes care of the finding the settings.

Comment: Thanks -- `python blossom/manage.py dumpdata` worked as expected.

Comment: True. Then why django docs are saying "Use exactly one of either configure() or DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE. Not both, and **not neither**." ?
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/settings/

Comment: Current thinking — as featured in the ["DeployDjango" site](http://www.deploydjango.com/django_project_structure/index.html) and the recent *[Two Scoops of Django](http://django.2scoops.org/)* book — is that `django-admin.py` with separated settings functions perfectly well, and is actually preferable to using `manage.py`.

Comment: But, but.. but.. what about [dumpdata](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/django-admin/#dumpdata). I need that in my life.

Answer (score 30):

I just encountered the same error, and eventually managed to work out what was going on (the big clue was `(Is it on sys.path?)` in the `ImportError`).

You need add your project directory to `PYTHONPATH` — this is what the documentation means by

> Note that the settings module should be on the Python import search path.

To do so, run

```
$ export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:$PWD
```

from the `~/dev/django-project` directory before you run `django-admin.py`.

You can add this command (replacing `$PWD` with the actual path to your project, *i.e.* `~/dev/django-project`) to your virtualenv's `source` script. If you choose to advance to [virtualenvwrapper](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenvwrapper) at some point (which is designed for this kind of situation), you can add the `export PY...` line to the auto-generated `postactivate` hook script.

[mkdjangovirtualenv](https://github.com/mrcoles/mkdjangovirtualenv) automates this even further, adding the appropriate entry to the Python path for you, but I have not tested it myself.

Comment: Dirty. But working and useful. You're encouraging circumventing problems. If something is not on sys.path, this means it needs to be packaged and installed, not hacked onto sys.path. I know, I'm solving one problem, creating two more.

Comment: Interesting: how do you think an in-development Django project should be added to `sys.path`, if not by `manage.py`, `django-admin.py`'s `--pythonpath` option, or the `PYTHONPATH` env var (none of which seems "dirtier" than the others..)

Comment: Package it (create setup.py) and install via pip inestall [-e]. Have a look at longer explenation: https://gist.github.com/bartekbrak/42d59fd43a9af14a0cc5

Answer (score 19):

On unix-like machine you can simply alias virtualenv like this and use alias instead of typing everytime:

.bashrc

`alias cool='source /path_to_ve/bin/activate; export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=django_settings_folder.settings; cd path_to_django_project; export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:$PWD'`

Comment: this actually solved my problem compared to the other answers. thanks!

Answer (score 7):

My favourite alternative is passing settings file as runtime parameter to `manage.py` in a python package syntax, e.g:

```
python manage.py runserver --settings folder.filename
```

more info [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#cmdoption-settings)

Comment: By far this approach is simple and saves trouble of configuring DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE every time you need to to using a different settings.py.

Answer (score 2):

I know there are plenty answers, but this one worked for me just for the record.

1. Navigate to your `.virtual_env` folder where all the virtual environments are.
2. Go to the environment folder specific to your project
3. Append `export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=<django_project>.settings`
   or `export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=<django_project>.settings.local` if you are using a separate settings file stored in a settings folder.

Answer (score 0):

Yet another way to do deal with this issue is to use the python dotenv package and include PYTHONPATH and DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE in the .env file along with your other environment variables. Then modify your manage.py and wsgi.py to load them as stated in the instructions.

```
from dotenv import load_dotenv
load_dotenv()
```

Answer (score 0):

I had similar error while working on windows machine. My problem was using wrong debug configuration. Use *Python:django* as your debug config option.
First ensure you've exported/set django_settings_module correctly [here.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/settings/)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue when changing out my virtualenv environment (stupid idea, btw). I tried setting DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE and it didn't work. My fix, instead of starting my server with:

```
django-admin runserver
```

I now run my server with this command:

```
python manage.py runserver
```

No other changes needed!