# What is the correct way to set DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE in a production/staging environments?

Tags: django, gunicorn, django-settings, virtualenvwrapper, django-wsgi

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8826534/how-can-i-correctly-set-django-settings-module-for-my-django-project-i-am-using) asks but the answer isn't about using Gunicorn.

How do I correctly set `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` to production in my production environment, and to staging in my staging environment?

I have two settings files - `staging.py` and `production.py`.

Because I was having trouble setting the variables, I simply made my default lines in manage.py and wsgi.py look like:

manage.py

```
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "settings.production")
```

wsgi.py

```
import os
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "settings.production") 

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

...so that in production, no matter the shenanigans with this pesky variable, my production app would remain on production settings if `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` wasn't set.

The problem is that I want my staging app to remain on staging settings so that emails don't go out from that (separate) server.

I have the above files in staging, as well as these attempts to properly set `settings.staging`:

gunicorn.conf:

```
description "Gunicorn daemon for Django project"

start on (local-filesystems and net-device-up IFACE=eth0)
stop on runlevel [!12345]

# If the process quits unexpectadly trigger a respawn
respawn

setuid django
setgid django
chdir /src

script
    export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE="settings.staging"
    exec /opt/Envs/mysite/bin/gunicorn \
        --name=mysite \
        --pythonpath=/opt/Envs/mysite/lib/python2.7/site-packages \
        --bind=127.0.0.1:9000 \
        --config /src/bin/gunicorn/gunicorn.py \
        mysite.wsgi:application
end script
```

Also, a file named `/etc/profile.d/myenvvars.sh` that contains:

```
export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=settings.staging
```

And finally, I'm using virtualenvwrapper, with this line in `/opt/Envs/myappenv/bin`:

```
export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=settings.staging
```

As you can see, I'm trying the belt and suspenders technique to keep settings to staging on the staging server. However, despite these FOUR ways of trying to set `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=settings.staging`, it's still sometimes defaulting to `settings.production` and sending out emails.

What is the proper way to set `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` once and for all on both my staging and production servers?