# Django "settings are not configured" error and cannot define environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE

Tags: python, django

This error is easy to reproduce. Basically just start a new django project and run the server with django-admin. I read many StackOverflow posts and tried multiple methods but did not work. Here are the detailed steps to reproduce:

1. Created new directory named `testproject`
2. `pipenv install django`
3. Started new project named `test` with the django start project script
4. `pipenv shell`
5. `django-admin runserver`
6. Error: `"django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting DEBUG, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings."`
7. Typed this in ubuntu as suggested in the official django docs:  `export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=test.settings`
8. `django-admin runserver`
9. Got a giant line of error followed by `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'test'`. However, if i do `django-admin runserver --pythonpath=. --settings="test.settings"` the server successfully runs.

I know I can just use python manage.py to start the server but my project uses Django cache framework and when I try to access the cache the same `settings are not configured` error is thrown. Trying to understand what is going on, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried `python manage.py runserver`?

Comment: Export pythonpath solved the issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8826534/how-can-i-correctly-set-django-settings-module-for-my-django-project-i-am-using

Comment: @Klaus D. Yes i did and it worked, but I think that's because in manage.py the env var is set for me: ```os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'test.settings')```

Comment: Just to make it clear: you should use `manage.py` instead of `django-admin`, it configures project specific things like the PYTHONPATH.

Comment: I understand that and that's why I added comments regarding the use of Django cache framework because accessing the cache gives the same error: ```Requested setting CACHES, but settings are not configured```. I'm using django-admin to simplify and reproduce the error without having django cache to be involved

Answer (score 0):

In your list I did not see the virtual env activation.

Did you activate the virtual env ?

'''
source activate testproject
'''