# Setting up project specific DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE in a machine with multiple django projects

Tags: django, deployment, environment-variables

My virtual machine is currently hosting a django (ngsdbview) project (Django 1.5/gunicorn/nginx with virtualenv setup). Instead of using default settings files, I have /settings/production.py (or dev.py etc)set up. So, I had earlier defined the DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE variable for the machine.

Now, I am adding a second django project (samples) to the same machine, and wonder how do I configure project specific  DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE variables?

Thanks,
Gowthaman

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass each settings file to guincorn separately for each project.  I'd recommend looking into [supervisord](http://supervisord.org/) to manage your guincorn processes so that you can keep one running for each project with different settings.

You can set up your config file like

```
[program:project1]
command=/var/www/project1/manage.py run_gunicorn --settings=project1.settings.production
directory=/var/www/project1/
environment=PATH="/var/www/project1/venv/bin"
user=www-data
autostart=true
autorestart=true

[program:project2]
command=/var/www/project2/manage.py run_gunicorn --settings=project2.settings.production
directory=/var/www/project2/
environment=PATH="/var/www/project2/venv/bin"
user=www-data
autostart=true
autorestart=true
```

So instead of defining it in an environment variable, you can define your settings in your supervisord config file, which will then maintain the process for each of your projects.

Answer (score 0):

the solution by Tim Edgar works well and I prefer that.

Meanwhile taking a hint from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7598793/setting-django-settings-module-under-virtualenv) i added 
`export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=myproject.settings.production` 
in bin/activate script. This works too. But, adding to activate script may not be an optimal solution as that goes away with every recreation/new deployment of virtual machine.